# How the comfirmations are established in a blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

If only the source initiates the transaction and broadcasts that information to the whole network, then it can also broadcast **false** information. So how does the other connected nodes verifies the confirmations of the transaction without actually querying the sender node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bitcoin transaction includes all information necessary to verify its validity. Once broadcast to the network the other nodes will be able to verify it independently. Invalid transactions are rejected from the network so you can't broadcast invalid transactions/false information